# Can we use the GCM / Notifications using PhoneGap?

Tags: android, html, notifications, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I want to know if we can use PhoneGap for multiple-purposes. I actually want to differnetiate the native android app and PhoneGap app.
I am using Notification services on my exiting Android app. Also I am using WebServices to interact with the data.
Can the same app being built in PhoneGap used for Notification and Webservices?

Appreciate instant Help.

Regards,
Nagesh...